# glColorMask/glDepthMask vs fragment shader

Tags: opengl-es, stencil-buffer

In OpenGL ES 2.0, if writes to the color buffer and depth buffer are disabled with glColorMask/glDepthMask (because I only want to change the stencil buffer), there are no buffers the fragment shader could write anything to. Can I reasonably assume that the fragment shader won't be executed in this case?

Comment: I think it will be  executed but the output won't be written into pixel / depth  buffer....

Comment: Are you asking if there would be any performance gain from swapping your program with one that has a minimal no-op fragment shader?

Comment: Yes, that's another way to put it.